# Javascript - open browser tab after clicking a service-worker notification on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, notifications, service-worker

I'm making a web app for a restaurant and have gotten to the point where my Notifications let me know when a new order has been taken. The app's workflow is:

1) A waiter logs in through Android Chrome to check pending tickets
2) A client registers a ticket using another device
3) A Notification is shown on the waiter's device

Up to this point, everything works fine. What I want to know is: is there any way that clicking the Notification while using another app (or while looking at the Home Screen) opens up Chrome on the corresponding tab (where the waiter logged in)?

Here is my code:

**App.js**

```
var n = _registration.showNotification('Menú',{
     body: 'Tienes un nuevo pedido',
     requireInteration: true,
});
```

**Service worker**

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    let url = 'https://example.com/some-path/';
    event.preventDefault();

    event.notification.close(); // Android needs explicit close.
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
            // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];
                // If so, just focus it.
                if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
            if (clients.openWindow) {
                return clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

This works perfectly fine from a desktop browser, but since the waiter uses an Android phone it would not be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Note: there is a small typo "requireIntera**c**tion"

Answer (score 2):

For me, `client.focus()` also doesn't work, but when I click on the notification — it actually focuses my app. 
And the difference in my code is that I do not have `event.preventDefault();`